# Multiple AND OR logic in the where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider the following scenario

I want to select all columns from table A where

1. SubscribeDate is between `2016-01-01` and `now()` and `clubid=2`
2. `timesbilled>0` and `clubid=2`

I am trying the following (The sample is big enough to have the sample)

```
Select *

From Table A

Where 
SubscribeDate between '2016-01-01' and now()
and clubid=2
OR
timesbilled>0
```

Will the query meet my requirement?

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: I want to consider the performance

Comment: So, why don't you test it? Do you have performance issues (performance is not described as a requirement)?

Comment: Alright man. You win. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase your query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE (SubscribeDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND NOW() OR timesbilled > 0) AND
      clubid = 2
```

Both of your listed conditions require a `clubid` of `2`.  The other requirement is that the date condition or billing condition be true.

Comment: How do you see @kuru's answer? That is more safe? or your's work with good performance?

Comment: Note that I simplified the clubs. The actual clubs are 11(eleven)

Comment: Our answers are logically identical, but you don't need to repeat `clubid = 2` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
Select *

From Table A

Where 
(SubscribeDate between '2016-01-01' and now()
and clubid=2)
OR
(timesbilled>0 and clubid=2);
```

Comment: Do we really have to declare it 2 times?

Comment: you can go with @Tim-Biegeleisen's solution, so you don't need to repeat

Comment: nope, both work same, that's simplified than my code. That's all

Comment: Thanks for your answer!